# Microsoft Graph Filter Public and Private Contacts

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I'm working with the ms graph contacts api.
Is it possible to filter public and private contacts using filter options?

Comment: Could you explain by what you mean by `public` vs `private`?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't follow. Are you using EWS or Graph? Either way, I'm not sure I understand what you mean by a "public contact" or a "private contact".

Comment: In Contacts, we can mark as private contact. So using the Exchange Web Services I can filter the contacts by using SearchFilterCollection. Here is the link for contact properties - (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.contact_properties(v=exchg.80).aspx)

Comment: @Marc Before using EWS i can filter with sensitivity property. But that property is not available in graph.

Comment: Ah, sensitivity make a lot more sense. :)

Answer (score 1):

The [sensitivity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.item.sensitivity(v=exchg.80).aspx) property isn't surfaced for [Contact](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/contact#properties) or [Message](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/message) objects in Microsoft Graph.

This property is only surfaced in the [Event](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/event#properties) object where it is used to determine how a given event is rendered for other users within the organization.

Comment: Do you know how can we filter that contacts which is mark as private in outlook contact by using the graph api?

Comment: At the moment this isn't possible but you can file a request for this at https://officespdev.uservoice.com/. Given that it is available in the UX, it certainly should be looked at.

Comment: 4 years later, I'm wondering if this is possible yet? User Voice appears to be shut down, so not sure where else to ask. Trying to determine whether a Contact is marked as private, i.e. Sensitive. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found the legacy extended property filter method. This worked for me:

/me/contacts?$filter=singleValueExtendedProperties/Any(ep: ep/id eq 'Integer 0x0036' and cast(ep/value, Edm.Int32) eq 2)

Used [this resource](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/main/api-reference/beta/api/singlevaluelegacyextendedproperty-get.md). The bottom of that page also demonstrates the cast to integer. The value 0x0036 is for PR_SENSITIVITY per [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidtagsensitivity-canonical-property). The value 2 is 'Private' per [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/exchange-server/exchange-10/ms526106(v=exchg.10)).